# Checking ColorIndex property of the range of Cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have strange problem. Let's say I have range of cells A5-J5 and I tinker with their colors. I change ColorIndex property based on some conditions. If the whole range has the same color I want to trigger some actions. Easy enough. When I change color of all cells in range manually (to black which ColorIndex is 1) the below code returns "TRUE" and everything works fine.

```
Sub test()
    If Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(5, 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
        MsgBox "TRUE"
    Else
        MsgBox "FALSE"
    End If
End Sub
```

However I do not want to change cell fill manually of course. I am using VBA code that changes their ColorIndex when some conditions are met. After whole range is changed to ColorIndex=1 with VBA code, the below code returns FALSE.

```
Sub testt()

    If Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(5, 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
        MsgBox "TRUE"
    Else
        MsgBox "FALSE"
    End If

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        MsgBox Cells(5, i).Interior.ColorIndex & " Cell no " & i

    Next i
End Sub
```

To check if every cell in this range has the same ColorIndex I loop through them. Every cell has ColorIndex=1. However whole range does not it seems - because it returns FALSE. This occures only if I change color of cells with VBA, when I do it matually everything runs just fine.

I know that I do not provide too many details, however perhaps someone here had simillar problem. Sorry if this question is too trivial but I really do not find any logical explanation to this.

Comment: not sure what you mean cause `Range("A5:A10").Interior.ColorIndex = 1` and `Debug.Assert Range("A5:A10").Interior.ColorIndex = 1` doesn't stop the execution. How are you changing the `Color` property in vba

Comment: I change color of cells if proper conditions is met. I use cells().interior.colorindex=1. If I change every cell to colorindex=1 with VBA whole range does not have ColorIndex=1. If I change cells manually to black the whole range has ColorIndex=1. There is some diffrence between changing it manually and with VBA but I do not know why.

Comment: there shouldn't be. Can you show your complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following code and it works just fine:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
CheckColor
End Sub

Sub CheckColor()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet

If Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(5, 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
    sh.Range("A1") = "True"
Else
    sh.Range("A1") = "False"
End If

End Sub

Sub SetColor()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rn As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set sh = ActiveSheet
Set rn = sh.Range("A5:J5")

For Each cl In rn
    cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
Next

CheckColor

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I used it to test my small project. The problem was generated by NULL value. If you check .ColorIndex of range that has multiple colors returned value is NULL and it messed up my code. Sorry for bad question.